# Multiple Forms on a Single Page - JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have multiple forms on a single page with the same named variables within each form.

I need to be able to changed the specific values for one form but not the others.

Ie.

I want to be able to set the value of Var2 for form2, but not the values of Var2 for form1.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Ideally, give the forms their own IDs and use the [Descendant Selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/):

```
$("#form1 input[name=foo]").val("something");
```

or select it by the order in which it appears in the DOM using `eq` (as Alxandr points out):

```
$("form:eq(0) input[name=foo]").val("something"); // select the first form
```

Comment: Just to mention, this is given that the form1 has the id of form1. You can also change `#form1` with `form:eq(0)` for instance. This will get the first form on the page, however, going with ids is the best way to go about it, because then you can replace the forms later etc.

Comment: Selecting the forms by their index/order in the page can be rather fragile, though. For instance, if you add/remove any other forms before the ones you are identifying. (say, a search box that is added to the whole site via the header/side bar)